# fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock (again)

Tags: go, deadlock

i got a wierd crash happening with my dicerolling program. It works fine but in the end it always says:

fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]: main.main() /tärning.go:43 +0x746

goroutine 6 [chan receive]: main.dice(0xc00003a0c0, 0xc00003a120, 0xc0000100a0) /tärning.go:51 +0x106 created by main.main /tärning.go:40 +0x59a

goroutine 7 [chan receive]: main.dice(0xc00003a0c0, 0xc00003a120, 0xc0000100a0) /tärning.go:51 +0x106 created by main.main /tärning.go:41 +0x5d3 exit status 2

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "math/rand"
)

type tärning struct {
    rubrik string
    minTal, maxTal int
}

type tärningsSvar struct {
    rubrik string
    svaret int
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fmt.Println("Dags att kasta tärningar")
    var antal int
    fmt.Println("Hur många tärningar vill du använda?")
    fmt.Scan(&antal)
    job := make(chan tärning, antal)
    svar := make(chan tärningsSvar, antal)
    for i := 0; i < antal; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Vad ska tärning", i+1, "ha för rubrik?")
        var text string
        fmt.Scan(&text)
        fmt.Println("Vad ska vara minsta värdet på tärningen?")
        var minsta int
        fmt.Scan(&minsta)
        fmt.Println("Vad ska vara största värdet på tärningen?")
        var största int
        fmt.Scan(&största)
        job <- tärning{rubrik: text, minTal: minsta, maxTal: största}
    }
    go dice(job, svar, &wg)
    go dice(job, svar, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    for svaren := range svar {
        fmt.Println("Tärning " + svaren.rubrik + " fick: ", svaren.svaret)
    }
}

func dice(job chan tärning, svar chan tärningsSvar, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1) 
    for item := range job {
        text := item.rubrik
        min := item.minTal
        max := item.maxTal
        slump := (rand.Intn(max - min) + min)
        svar <- tärningsSvar{rubrik: text, svaret: slump}
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: You buffered channel is too small.

Comment: Nope, the channels are exactly the perfect size, but thx for trying, the channels size is dependent on how big of a work that should be done, if there is 5 dices that should be thrown, both the job channel and the channel for the answers is 5 in size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed your code here: https://play.golang.org/p/ZgRRb-wOdDk with comments. Please check.

There are multiple issues in your code.
1. The way you have used  `wg.Add(1)` in your code, it will not work. you have to put `wg.Add(2)`  before starting your go routines and remove the `wg.Add(1)` from dice function since there could be a race situation and your `wg.Add(1)` can run when `wg.Wait()` ran already.

2. You are ranging on a channel job. You didn't close any of your channel. Also, the range query is a blocking call. In the meantime, your `svaren := range svar` will be blocked as well since no one will add item to it. So, program will stuck in a situation where main function is blocked to read data from `svar` channel. and also, `dice` function is stuck because there is no data in `job` channel and it is blocked in `item := range job` step.
3. So, if both go routines wait for one another it will lead to a deadlock situation.

Comment: Thanks, it really help me much, im pretty new to golang and sometimes its kinda hard to learn everything by yourself. Once again, THANK YOU!

Comment: Great answer but I would remove "you try to read from the channel where there could be no data in that channel due to insufficient buffer space" as it doesn't make any sense. If there's no data in the channel, it doesn't matter how large the buffer is, or if there is a buffer at all; it's empty.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian . I was also thinking about that. I will update my answer.